# Why doesnt salt export and command execution happen?

Tags: salt-stack

I have a salt state file (approach 1):

```
export_port:
  cmd.run:
    - name: export PORT=53000
    - cwd: /tmp
execute_cmd:
  cmd.run:
    - name: ./test.sh db host user log
    - cwd: /tmp
```

When a job is executed, the state file returns an error stating that the psql program is not installed.

I tried the salt sate file with a shell script which has all the export and shell commands above (approach 2):

```
script:
  cmd.script:
    - name: /tmp/test.sh
    - source: /source/dir/test.sh
    - cwd: /tmp
```

And the shell script has:

```
#! /bin/sh
export PORT=53000
./test.sh db host user log
```

Both the approach are for same task to export a value and execute a command. The second approach works fine as expected. I am not sure why the first approach failed. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is you're executing two `cmd.run` sequentially, each one spawning a new and independent shell, so the environment variable exported in the first is not available in the second one.

It should work with

```
execute_cmd:
  cmd.run:
    - name: PORT=53000 ./test.sh db host user log
    - cwd: /tmp
```

or better using the env parameter defined in cmd.run doc https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html#salt.states.cmd.run

```
execute_cmd:
  cmd.run:
    - name: ./test.sh db host user log
    - cwd: /tmp
    - env:
      - PORT: 53000
```

Comment: daks: I will try your suggestion, between am trying the above for multiple env variables.

Comment: Can I specify multiple variables like below? It dont seem to be working though.
    execute_cmd:
      cmd.run:
        - name: ./test.sh db host user log
        - cwd: /tmp
        - env:
           - PORT: 53000
           - NAME: name
           - USER: user

Comment: it should, like written in the doc.

Comment: I just tested and it works fine, maybe update your question with information about the sls you wrote

Comment: Thanks daks, I added double quotes to env variables and it worked.